# unable to view sharepoint list created through BCS external list from designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, bcs

IM using BCS connecting to local DB from SharePoint site in designer creating external lists but i'm facing error as below :

> Cannot connect to the LobSystem (External System). Reason: 'A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network interfaces error: 52 - Unable to locate Database runtime
>   installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and
>   the Local Database Runtime Feature is enabled.)'

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs because of a **connection issue** between your `External List` and its `External Content Type Data Source` (DB Server).

**Some points to trace your issue:**

- Make sure that the DB server is up and running.
- Make sure that the Db server is reachable from app server using Ping cmdlet.
- Make sure that you are able to connect to the SQL server instance from App Server check [HOW TO CHECK SQL SERVER INSTANCE CONNECTIVITY FROM THE APPLICATION SERVER TO DATABASE SERVER FOR A SPECIFIC USER WITHOUT USING SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/28/check-sql-server-instance-connectivity/)
- Make sure that the SQL server services are running.
  [image]
- Check with your system admin to the firewall status.
- Reconfigure the external content type data source again.